# OS-independent grunt script command in NPM package.json

Tags: windows, npm, gruntjs

When the command `grunt` is run in a Windows shell in the same path as the grunt.js file, Windows opts to run grunt.js using the Windows Script Host. [The recommended path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176623/23501) is to explicitly call `grunt.cmd`.

That's all fine and dandy, but what can I do if I want to create an OS-independent script command in my NPM package.json? I can't do this if I want to also run in *nix:

```
"scripts": {
    "dox": "grunt.cmd dox"
}
```

Any pointers? Or, is there a big piece of the puzzle that I'm missing? (I'm equally new to both NPM and Grunt).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution in creating a `grunt.bat` file that just calls `grunt.cmd`:

```
@grunt.cmd %*
```

Therefore, on Windows, just invoking `grunt` triggers the batch file since it gets higher priority than Windows Scripting Host's picking up of `grunt.js`. On Linux, the regular `grunt` binary gets picked up. This works cross-platform for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem: when there is `tslint.js` file in the root dir of the package and an npm script in `package.json` just calls `tslint`, jscript is fired by npm instead of node, resulting in "Microsoft JScript compilation error" popup.

A workaround is removing `.JS` from `PATHEXT` environment variable.